# How to add session from database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I still new using Asp.net with vb.net

```
Protected Sub login_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles login.Click
        Dim querystrings As String = "Select Email, Password ,Roles, Nama_Depan, Nama_Belakang from Employee where Email = @email;"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(connected)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(querystrings, con)
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader

   Session ("Namadepan")= cmd.Parameters("Nama_Depan")

end sub
```

I wanted to store Roles, Nama_Depan, Nama_Belakang with session but i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class that handles this logic so `Session()` and `Session.Add()` isn't scattered throughout your website.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As ClassStoredInSession
    Get
        'store the object in session if it is not already stored
        If Session("example") Is Nothing Then
            Session("example") = New ClassStoredInSession()
        End If

        'return the object stored in session
        Return DirectCast(Session("example"), ClassStoredInSession)
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class namely `UserSession` which have it's properties as the data retrieved from the database and insert the instance of the class into `Session` object.

Pseudocode :

```
UserSession user = new UserSession(name , roles .... )
Session["userData"] = user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: [Save values in Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb)

It is as simple as:

```
Session("Namadepan") = cmd.Parameters["Nama_Depan"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the result of you SqlDataReader and store it in session.

After executing the sql command against your server myReader should contain the data you need.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.71)

you can then fetch the data from the reader and store it in your session. You can make a specific "UserData" object and store that in session.

Session("UserData") = new UserData{}

Answer (score 0):

Session("username") = myreader("Nama_Depan")